# AccountName field not accessible on Order object

Tags: soql, order

Not able to use this SOQL in Apex:

```
Order currectOrder = [SELECT AccountNumber, OrderNumber, Type, Status FROM Order WHERE Id =: currentOrderId];
```

getting error:

```
No such column 'AccountNumber' on entity 'Order'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.`enter code here`
```

This field is visible for System Administrators by default, so it does not seem to be a permission issue. Performing SOQL in my own Dev Edition, field is needed for Read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name is `AccountId` and not AccountNumber.

Use below SOQL

```
Order currectOrder = [SELECT AccountId, OrderNumber, Type, Status FROM Order WHERE Id =: currentOrderId];
```

If you need AccountNumber then you can use below SOQL that uses Relationship in SOQL to pull info

```
Order currectOrder = [SELECT Account.AccountNumber, OrderNumber, Type, Status FROM Order WHERE Id =: currentOrderId];
```

Comment: Thanks, the second SOQL was exactly what I've been looking for. I was confused by "Object Manager" which shows that there's an AccountNumber field directly on Order field, which is not true